# How to get Git/Subversion 1.7 working on AIX 6.1?

Tags: git, svn, aix

I've downloaded the git 1.7.10 and subversion 1.7.4 RPMs from http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php, but when I try to run git svn I get this problem:

```
multi/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so'
for module SVN::_Core: rtld: 0712-001 Symbol svn_handle_warning was
referenced
     from module
/opt/freeware/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/ppc-thread-multi/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so(),
but a runtime definition
           of the symbol was not found.
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol svn_handle_warning2 was referenced
     from module
/opt/freeware/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/ppc-thread-multi/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so(),
but a runtime definition
           of the symbol was not found.
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol svn_error_clear was referenced
     from module
/opt/freeware/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/ppc-thread-multi/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so(),
but a runtime definition
           of the symbol was not found.
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol svn_error_compose was referenced
     from module
/opt/freeware/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/ppc-thread-multi/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so(),
but a runtime definition
           of the symbol was not found.
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol svn_swig_pl_make_pool was referenced
     from module
/opt/freeware/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/ppc-thread-multi/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so(),
but a runtime definition
           of the symbol was not found.
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol svn_diff_hunk_reset_modified_text was referenced
     from module
/opt/freeware/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/ppc-thread-multi/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so(),
but a runtime definition
           of the symbol was not found.
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol svn_diff_hunk_reset_original_text was referenced
     from module
/opt/freeware/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/ppc-thread-multi/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so(),
but a runtime definition
           of the symbol was not found.
Additional errors occurred but are not reported. at
/opt/freeware/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ppc-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 227.
 at /opt/freeware/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/ppc-thread-multi/SVN/Base.pm
line 59
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
/opt/freeware/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/ppc-thread-multi/SVN/Core.pm
line 5.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/freeware/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 41.
-bash-3.2$ nm -g _Core.so | grep svn_handle_warning
._wrap_svn_handle_warning T   268581888         808
._wrap_svn_handle_warning2 T   268582696        1048
.svn_handle_warning  T   268469632
.svn_handle_warning2 T   268469672
_wrap_svn_handle_warning D   536899412
_wrap_svn_handle_warning2 D   536899400
svn_handle_warning   U           -
svn_handle_warning2  U           -
```

So, it appears to me that Core.so wasn't built correctly.

Can anyone outline how I might go about debugging fix a problem of this kind?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java on your system, I would recommend you to install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into your SVN server and use any of SVN or Git interfaces. SubGit will sync Git and SVN repositories on-the-fly. The repositores and blocked while synchronization (for a couple of seconds), so this solution is concurrency-safe.

If you need a client-only solution you may try [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). It is java-based too, so won't suffer from your git-svn/perl problems.

Both solutions perform better SVN<->Git translation preserving such concepts as EOLs, ignores, tags and so on (git-svn doesn't).

Comment: Thanks - this doesn't work for me. I am not at liberty to modify the SVN server and I don't want my end users to have a dependency on a reliable, fast network to the SVN server. So git-svn running on the AIX server is actually the best fit for my requirements, assuming I can get it to work.